# PHP & JS numeric and assoc arrays index trouble

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

This problem is probably trivial for 99% of you. So far I always tried to avoid situation like this, but now I don't have any choice.

```
For PHP:
$array = array();
$array[5] = 'Element';
$array['s_5'] = 'Alternative Element';
$array[7] = 'Element2';
$array['s_7 '] = 'Alternative Element2';

For JS
var array = new Array();
array[5] = 'Element';
array['s_5'] = 'Alternative Element';
array[7] = 'Element2';
array['s_7 '] = 'Alternative Element2';
```

And now I need to get to secondth element of array. How to do it? Of course I could create another table containing array keys for each element, or use foreach/while and do some action on specific element. Also I can get last array element in PHP using end(), but is there any other, faster way to get specific element from random array (implying I don't know keys and length of array)?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Your JS is incorrect. Arrays are ordered lists indexed by numbers. You seem to want a Javascript Object which can use non-numeric member identifiers. -- Like a hash in other languages. Hashes are not ordered by definition. But you could create an array to keep track of the order with which you added items to your hash/object.

Comment: There are **no** associative arrays in JS. At all. Object are **unordered**. You cannot mix syntax this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a 2 dimensional array instead:

```
$matrix = array();
$matrix['elements'] = array();
$matrix['alt_elements'] = array();

$matrix['elements'][5] = 'Element';
$matrix['alt_elements'][5] = 'Alternative Element';
```

etcetera...

Avoid using associative arrays in JS. Use arrays only when the keys are numeric. Otherwise, use objects.

```
var matrix = {};
matrix.elements = [];
matrix.altElements = [];

matrix.elements[5] = 'Element';
matrix.altElements[5] = 'Alternative Element';
```

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays (php) or objects (js) are not meant to be accesed by numeric index. This includes accessing the n-th element.

If you really have to do it there's no good way except iterating over the array using `foreach($arr as $key => $val)` in php or `for(var key in obj)` in js and counting the elements manually.

However, if your arrays resemble a matrix, you might want to create two matrices or make the innermost element an array so you have plain numeric arrays for the actual matrix and just for the data inside something else.